# VMware ESXi 5.5 black screen on all guests after services.sh restart

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I'm using VMware ESXi 5.5.0 1331820 with a eight Windows guests. Sometimes I can't connect anymore via vSphere Client to the host.

A restart of the hostd and vpxa doesn't resolve the problem. So, I need to restart the services with the command services.sh. After this I can connect again to the host via vSphere Client.

But then I see only a black screen in the Console-view on each guest. It seems that the VMware Tools on each guest are down or not running.

If I send a reboot command to guest A from guest B, the problem still persists on guest A.

If I send a shutdown command to guest A from guest B so it's completely down, and then a power on, the Console-view is ok.

Do you have any tips or solutions for me?

Best regards,
Ronny

Comment: Are you sure the black screen in Console-view is not just the screen-saver? Are the guests still responding to the network? Have you accessed their log files, and what do they say? Please give more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VMware ESXi build 1331820 - 22 SEPT 2013**

**[Update your VMware.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6195/13325)**

There's no excuse to be running such an old version of ESXi. You know they have periodic updates and patches, right?

The current build is 3248547. Try that.

[image]

Comment: thank you. I'll try to update the ESXi to build 3248547.
Hope this resolves the problems....

Comment: Update build 3248547 successfully performed today.
I'll tell you in a few days, if the problems still exists.

Comment: Thank you - it seems that the update resolves the problem at this time.
Crazy - i have the build version 1331820 over 1 year without any troubles. 
No changes made in this year....suddenly the problems occurs.